# Simulate iPhone from the backup

Tags: iphone, backup, xcode-simulator

I am currently having some problems with my iPhone making it impossible to connect to it. I did perform a full backup before it died.

My question is, is it possible to simulate my iPhone using the backup? And if so, how?

Answer (score 1):

It isn't possible to *simulate* the iPhone contents from the backup. The possible resort is to restore the backup on the device after resolving the issue or get another iPhone to restore onto.

Answer (score 0):

Try connecting your iPhone to your computer and go to iTunes and that may allow you to backup/restore your phone.